# how to get nested scrapy - selectors

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

How can I get the xpath of 'img src' of the following html

```
<a class=product-tile">
 <img src="image-file-here">
</a>
```

Comment: Do you actually need an xpath? It'd be easier/more versatile to use a CSS selector here... and do you want the `img` element or the actual `src` attribute of the `img` ?

Comment: I need the actual src attribute of the  image

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to extract the value for the src attribute, if so this should solve the issue:

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="product-tile"]/img/@src').get()
```

[Scrapy docs on selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector which is easier and converted to XPATH underhood.

Try this

```
response.css('.product-tile ::attr(src)').get()
```

Comment: I'd probably go for: `a.product-tile > img::attr(src)`

Comment: We generally avoid HTML tags while writing selectors as they are more likely to change and inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for XPTH here is what you can use to get image source for first find use extract_first()

```
response.xpath('//img/@src').extract_first()
```

if you have complex html you can use more specific xpath

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="product-tile"]/@src').extract_first()
```

if there are more than one images src links you want to extract use extract()

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="product-tile"]/@src').extract()
```

There could be more than one src links inside  tag like this

```html
<a class=product-tile">
 <img src="image-file-here">
 <a>
  <img src="image-file-here">
 </a>
 <img src="image-file-here">
 <img src="image-file-here">
</a>
```

so use // before @src

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="product-tile"]//@src').extract()
```